# How to remove the upper wheel of a bandsaw?

Tags: tool-maintenance, band-saw

I am in the process of restoring an old 14" bandsaw. I would like to disassemble it as much as possible and clean each part and remove as much saw dust and rust as I can.

My first major step is to remove the upper wheel but it seems stuck.

[image]

I have removed the nut in the middle and applied what I thought was a reasonable amount of force but it remains where it is.

I don't want to apply to much force or bang it because I don't want to damage the bearing or the bolt.

Any ideas on how I can remove the wheel?

Comment: I think you need something like a bearing puller, which will allow you to slowly back the wheel off its axle without putting undue strain on the arms or the periphery of the wheel (although I suspect it's very strong due to the reinforcing webbing in the castings it is better to err on the side of caution). You can build the device using scraps of plywood and a few screws. Basically you want something that holds against the inner edge of the wheel in a few spots with a central screw acting against the end of the axle, the pulling force being exerted by the screw being driven in.

Comment: In hopes of increasing your confidence, I'll say that I have a *very* similar bandsaw. After I removed that nut, the top wheel just slid right off. So I second what Graphus said. You're on the right track here.

Comment: Do you have the make and model of the bandsaw? Those kinds of things always help in these scenarios

Comment: @Matt it's a Champion. I haven't been able to find out much about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted something along the lines of @Graphus's suggestion but could t get it to work. There wasn't enough space behind the wheel to put anything there to brace it.

However, I banged the bolt lightly with a small hammer several times and noticed the wheel had moved a bit. I continued this for a while and pulled the wheel simultaneously and the wheel came off!

[image]

Comment: Percussive maintenance to the rescue once again :-) Glad you got it off and best of luck with putting the saw back into service. Oh and happy new year!